# How to Use Math captcha in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, struts, captcha

I have two images [image: Showing no. 2]
    [image: Showing no. 4]
In the JSP page i am using these images, so that user can sum the number shown in the images and then once he click the Submit.
If the Sum is correct, it should return "Correct Captcha" otherwise Incorrect.

For Example:
Image1(Contain No. 2) + Image2(Contain No. 4) = Once User Will add these No.(6)
Then only program should procedd.

Also how to put refresh button in this to change the images.
Any Help is appreciated!!!

Thanks In Advance

Comment: It's not really clear what specific issue(s) you're having.

Comment: I want to Use math captcha using JSP for my Web Application .
Please let me know if you want any other information...

Comment: Go for simple javascript/jQuery math captcha's given [sample](http://freezecoders.com/demos/replace-captcha-by-simple-Number-calculation-using%20Jquery-code.php) here.

Comment: When someone will disable the javascript then in that case it is not working

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement Math captcha you have to use Javascript & Jquery and using it on JSP is like using in on any HTML page